# Why is "omniscient" different from "know-it-alls"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I was proposing this sentence to a forum to be corrected:

> People start being omniscient should their cohesive minds have been
> eradicated by nonchalant demeanors.

I was trying to say (in plain English) like this:

> People will act they know everything in others' mind when they don't
> care about them.

Someone corrected my sentence and I'm still thinking that it would mean any difference:

> People become omniscient when their cohesive minds have been
> eradicated of nonchalant demeanors.

And suggested the word "know-it-alls" instead. I've also looked up the definition of "omniscient" from OALD that it also means knowing everything.

So what's the difference? And if you don't mind (optional, but needed) please tell me why doesn't my sentence make sense.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The example you made up may initially sound academic but to a native speaker it soon appears to be highly pretentious, artificial babble. When writing or speaking to a group of people use simple sentences. The aim is clear easy communication not sounding "clever".

Comment: @Mari-LouA but that's not the point of my question :)))) I'm intending to expand my vocabulary. And I love languages. I want to know every words that exist in English. I'm not trying to use this word to talk to people :) I just want to know the difference between those words. How I'm supposed to understand a language if every time I ask a question about "how to use this word" and "what's the difference between these words" people always assume I want to sound clever. no. And never. I mean who I am? I'm just a stupid learner aren't I?

Comment: I really wish people in this forum respected any kind of questions as long as those questions don't break the rule. :) For those downvoters especially. :) Or at least tell me what should I provide or add to make it clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Omniscient is a technical word that is used to talk about God.  God, we are told, knows *everything* in the past and in the future.  This is not something that can be non-ironically applied to humans.

A know-it-all is a human who shows off their knowledge (but nobody claims to literally know all things)

Unfortunately, the first sentence is grammatically incorrect to the point that it is unintelligible. The last sentence is a little better, but still incomprehensible. I have no idea what "cohesive minds" are, or what it would mean to "eradicate nonchalant demeanours".  You don't have demeanours in your mind, so you can't eradicate them.  And that has no connection to knowing everything. It also does not mean "when they don't care about them".